# Spartacus - Reload component on Currency or Language change

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am facing one issue related to currency and language change. Due to some implementation we had to rewrite the default spartacus service for product (product-service.ts) and instead of calling

```
return productCode
      ? this.productLoading.get(productCode, [].concat(scopes))
      : of(undefined);
```

We are calling directly our connector in order to get all information we need from the product. Problem that we are facing now is that when user is in PDP and wants to change currency or language, components that call product-service.ts do not update and keeps wrong information. How can I accomplish same default Spartacus behaviour but without using default code ?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the product scope endpoints? 
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/loading-scopes/#configuring-payload-for-scopes

Answer (score 0):

you can observe the currency and language context and then recalculate all your frontend data. For example if you need to reload based on the currency changing you can call this

```
this.currencyService.getActive().subscribe(() => {
  this.doSomething();
});
```

Same goes for the LanguageService.

I have to do the same, for updating payment options and it works really well.